# In JFreeChart, what is a winding rule?

Tags: java, jfreechart

In JFreeChart, what is a winding rule?

What significance are its values?

There is no javadoc or example for its usage that could be found.

Comment: I don't know jfreechart, but normally in computer graphics the winding rule determines how complex self intersecting shapes are filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37972970/230513), a winding rule applies to determining the interior of a path, typically for filling or intersecting. Because a [`GeneralPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html) can have one of [two different winding rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37973144/230513), [`ShapeUtils`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/util/ShapeUtils.html) must include it in the corresponding implementation of [`equal()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/util/ShapeUtils.html#equal-java.awt.geom.GeneralPath-java.awt.geom.GeneralPath-), seen [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/a362a41d4d944f6be5d3ec2f93c32bc975e10c0b/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/util/ShapeUtils.java#L224). Similarly, [`SerialUtils`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/util/SerialUtils.html) must include the attribute when serializing a `GeneralPath`, as seen [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/a362a41d4d944f6be5d3ec2f93c32bc975e10c0b/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/util/SerialUtils.java#L300).