# Add GeneralPath shape in XYShapeAnnotation of JFreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to adding a general shape to highlight an area where Y is greater than X in JFreechart.

for that i have defined a general path.

```
int x3Points[] = {0, (int) Math.max(maxX, maxY), (int) Math.max(maxX, maxY), 0};
int y3Points[] = {0, (int) Math.max(maxX, maxY), (int) maxY, (int) maxY};
GeneralPath filledPolygon = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD, x3Points.length);
filledPolygon.moveTo(x3Points[0], y3Points[0]);
    for (int index = 1; index < x3Points.length; index++) {
         filledPolygon.lineTo(x3Points[index], y3Points[index]);
     }
        filledPolygon.lineTo(x3Points[0], y3Points[0]);
        filledPolygon.closePath();

Graphics graphics = getGraphics(); // i am not sure if calling getGraphics() method of JFrame is a good idea. but if not how to get Graphics() to draw on chart 

   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
   g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

   g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
   g2d.setPaint(Color.gray);
   g2d.fill(filledPolygon);
   g2d.dispose();
   XYShapeAnnotation xyShapeAnnotation = new XYShapeAnnotation(filledPolygon, new BasicStroke(2.f), Color.black);

 renderer.addAnnotation(xyShapeAnnotation, Layer.BACKGROUND);
```

the shape is added to the chart but it is not filled with black color. i guess the getGraphics() method that i am using is not correct. but how to get graphics of JFreechart.

Comment: Do't use `getGraphics()` in this context; `addAnnotation()`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20addAnnotation), should suffice; also check you winding rule, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54318437/230513).

Comment: In my case i am setting `GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD` . when i remove `getGraphics()` and simply use `addAnnotation()`  shape is not filled it is only showing border of the shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `getGraphics()`; the returned graphics context will become [invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjava%5D%20don%27t%20getGraphics) after subsequent updates. Instead, specify the desired `fillPaint` in your [`XYShapeAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYShapeAnnotation.html) constructor. Later calls to [`draw()`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/5da94a14d497cf0741937b27365882515a12528e/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYShapeAnnotation.java#L148) will [`fill()`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/5da94a14d497cf0741937b27365882515a12528e/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYShapeAnnotation.java#L203) the `Shape` accordingly, as shown in the example below. Note a few common pitfalls:

- The desired `Layer` should be specified, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802375/230513).
- The shape coordinates must be specified in data space, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56587266/230513).
- The *winding rule* defines the interior for `fill()`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54318437/230513).

[image]

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.annotations.XYShapeAnnotation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.Layer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/59588078/230513
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35236100/261156
 */
public class AnnotationTest {

    private static final BasicStroke STROKE = new BasicStroke(2.0f);
    private static final int N = 16;
    private static final int W = 1;
    private static final int H = W;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new AnnotationTest()::display);
    }

    private void display() {
        XYDataset data = createDataset();
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Annotation Test", "X", "Y",
            data, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer
            = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.addAnnotation(new XYShapeAnnotation(initPath(4, 4),
            STROKE, Color.gray, Color.red), Layer.FOREGROUND);
        renderer.addAnnotation(new XYShapeAnnotation(initPath(8, 8),
            STROKE, Color.gray, Color.blue), Layer.FOREGROUND);
        renderer.addAnnotation(new XYShapeAnnotation(initPath(12, 12),
            STROKE, Color.gray, Color.green), Layer.FOREGROUND);
        ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Annotation Test", chart);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private GeneralPath initPath(int x, int y) {
        GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
        path.moveTo(x, y);
        path.lineTo(x - W, y - H);
        path.lineTo(x + W, y - H);
        path.lineTo(x - W, y + H);
        path.lineTo(x + W, y + H);
        path.lineTo(x, y);
        return path;
    }

    private static XYDataset createDataset() {
        XYSeriesCollection result = new XYSeriesCollection();
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Test");
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            series.add(i, i);
        }
        result.addSeries(series);
        return result;
    }
}
```